# Move "Login link" to right side from Bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm developing a `Django` website and I'm using `Bootstrap/CSS/HTML` in order to get an aesthetic look.

I created a `navbar menu` and I would like to place my `login tab` to the right side. But, it's maybe be stupid, I don't get a good result :

My **HTML script** looks like :

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
...
display all tabs
...

<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

<li><a href="{% url "logout" %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Déconnexion </a></li>
{% else %}
<li><a href="{% url "login" %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Connexion </align></a></li>
{% endif %}
</ul>
```

If user is connected :

[image]

And if user is not connected :

[image: enter code here]

I'm really new with HTML/CSS/Bootstrap so do you have any idea ?

Thank you

**EDIT :**

My entire HTML script with multiple `{% user.is_authenticated %}` :

```
<!--DOCTYPE html -->
<html>
    <head>

    {% load staticfiles %}

    <title> DatasystemsEC - Accueil </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />   
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/Base.css' %}"/>
    </head>

    <!-- #################### -->
    <!-- Upper navigation bar -->
    <!-- #################### -->

        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.test.fr/"> Logiciel </a>
                </div>

                <!-- Home tab -->

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="{% url "accueil" %}"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Accueil </a></li>

                <!-- Individual form tab -->
                    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                    <li class = "dropdown">
                        <a href = "accueil" class = "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-baby-formula"></span> Fiches Individuelles
                        <b class = "caret"></b>
                        </a>
                        <ul class = "dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href = "{% url "home" %}"> Accueil des fiches individuelles </a></li>
                            <li><a href = "{% url "form" %}"> Création des fiches individuelles </a></li>
                            <li><a href = "{% url "searched" %}"> Consultation des fiches individuelles </a></li>
                            <li><a href = "{% url "edited" %}"> Edition des fiches individuelles </a></li>
                            <li><a href = "{% url "deleted" %}"> Suppression des fiches individuelles </a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                <!-- Birth form tab -->

                    <li class = "dropdown">
                        <a href = "accueil" class = "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-baby-formula"></span> Actes de Naissance
                        <b class = "caret"></b>
                        </a>
                        <ul class = "dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href = "{% url "BChome" %}"> Accueil des actes de naissance </a></li>
                            <li><a href = "{% url "BCform" %}"> Création d'un acte de naissance </a></li>
                            <li><a href = "http://localhost:8080/"> Consultation d'un acte de naissance </a></li>
                            <li><a href = "{% url "BCnotfound" %}"> Edition d'un acte de naissance </a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                <!-- Wedding form tab -->

                    <li class = "dropdown">
                        <a href = "accueil" class = "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> Actes de Mariage
                        <b class = "caret"></b>
                        </a>
                        <ul class = "dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href = "{% url "BCnotfound" %}"> Accueil des actes de mariage </a></li>
                            <li><a href = "{% url "BCnotfound" %}"> Création des actes de mariage </a></li>
                            <li><a href = "{% url "BCnotfound" %}"> Consultation des actes de mariage </a></li>
                            <li><a href = "{% url "BCnotfound" %}"> Edition des actes de mariage </a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                <!-- Divorce form tab -->

                <li class = "dropdown">
                        <a href = "accueil" class = "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span> Actes de Divorce
                        <b class = "caret"></b>
                        </a>
                        <ul class = "dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href = "{% url "BCnotfound" %}"> Accueil des actes de divorce </a></li>
                            <li><a href = "{% url "BCnotfound" %}"> Création des actes de divorce </a></li>
                            <li><a href = "{% url "BCnotfound" %}"> Consultation des actes de divorce </a></li>
                            <li><a href = "{% url "BCnotfound" %}"> Edition des actes de divorce </a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                <!-- Death form tab -->

                    <li class = "dropdown">
                        <a href = "accueil" class = "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-alert"></span> Actes de Décès
                        <b class = "caret"></b>
                        </a>
                        <ul class = "dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href = "{% url "BCnotfound" %}"> Accueil des actes de décès </a></li>
                            <li><a href = "{% url "BCnotfound" %}"> Création des actes de décès </a></li>
                            <li><a href = "{% url "BCnotfound" %}"> Consultation des actes de décès </a></li>
                            <li><a href = "{% url "BCnotfound" %}"> Edition des actes de décès </a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                {% endif %}
                <!-- Connexion tab -->

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                    <li><a href="{% url "logout" %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Déconnexion </a></li>
                    {% else %}
                    <li><a href="{% url "login" %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Connexion </a></li>
                    {% endif %}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock content %}
</html>
```

Comment: There is an `</align>` tag after `Connexion` which might be interfering.

Comment: @ilovecoding Oh yes, I forgot to remove my last try ;) I have to place `<align></align>` tag, but I don't find a way to do that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just you have to put `{% endif %}` of the first `{% if user.is_authenticated %}` before  `</ul>` and it will work.

Comment: Thanks ! It works perfectly. Now I see, I wrote `{% endif %}` after the block  like `<ul>{% if_user.is_authenticaded %}</ul>{% endif %}` instead of  `<ul>{% if_user.is_authenticaded %}{% endif %}</ul>`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `position` property and set a `left` and `right` value for the elements.

```
<div style="positon: absolute; top: 30%; left: 20%">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li>item</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

or, you can use `style="float:right; margin: 10%;"`

Comment: I don't want to use CSS to do that, bootstrap is sufficient and I just have to play with `{% user.is_authenticated %}` tag ;)

Answer (score 0):

`.navbar-right` as you have in your template is the class that makes the links pull to the right side of the page. [See the docs here.](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-component-alignment) Though you don't show the full template it appears this tag gets cut off in the `{% else %}` section of your template.

Depending on your template you might need to include multiple `{% user.is_authenticated %}` tags. This would solve your issue based on the template fragment above:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
...
display all tabs
...
{% endif %}

<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<li><a href="{% url "logout" %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Déconnexion </a></li>
{% else %}
<li><a href="{% url "login" %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Connexion </align></a></li>
{% endif %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes exactly, so my `{% else %}` tag is not well-placed ? I would like to just put "login" where users are not logged, and "logout" when users are already logged.

Comment: @Valentin you'd have to show your template. It's possible that you could just move the `%{ else %}` tag but more likely that you need to add more than one `{% user.is_authenticated %}` tag as I showed in my update.

Comment: Yes, I've already tried to insert mutiple `{% user.is_authenticated %}` but none effects. Do you want I paste my whole HTML script (120 lines) ?

Comment: @Valentin that would help

Comment: Entire script is above in order to find solution